# IOS Duplicate Class JSON in Dropbox and GData API

Tags: ios, class, duplicates, gdata, dropbox

I am using GData with my APP, Also i am trying to implement DropBox with my App but having an error of duplicate class JSON, ERROR IS:

> ld: duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_SBJSON in
>   /Users/imansermini/Desktop/My
>   Apps/DocumentList/DropboxSDK.framework/DropboxSDK and
>   /Users/imansermini/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DocumentList-edgyyvpajkkdolgdngxapaookhkc/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/libGDataTouchStaticLib.a(SBJSON.o)
>   for architecture i386 Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/llvm-gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Can anyone tell me is there any solution to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must have SBJson twice added into your project.
you need to find the same in your project hierarchy and "delete reference only" for the same.

Comment: Yes it was into both API's and solved my problem by just removing JSON from GData Cause i am not using JSON with GData. Thankyou!